# Icon is not displaying on check-box in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, firefox

I am facing a problem that i have created a checkbox displaying + and - for expand and collapse.
HTML Code -

```
<input type=checkbox class="ins" ng-model=show ng-class='{open:show}'><b>Show</b>
```

CSS code is -

```
 .ins {
        -moz-appearance:none;
        -o-appearance:none;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        width: 14px;
        height: 14px;
    }
    .ins:after {

        content: ' + ';
        font-weight: 800;

    }
    .ins.open[type=checkbox]:after {

        content:" - ";
        font-weight: 800;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1jj1714e/

it works perfectly fine on chrome, but same code not works on Mozilla

Comment: it is not functioning in my jsfiddle.... would you like another comprehensive example of the same functionality ? tested with all the browsers ? I've been working on exact same thing lately....

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1jj1714e/
This is working code..

Comment: `:before` and `:after` is not available on elements that cannot have content. `<input type="checkbox" />` is one of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:before` and `:after` is not available on elements that cannot have content. `<input type="checkbox" />` is one of those.

Others:

- `<input type="radio" />`
- `<input type="text/date/email/number/whathaveyou" />`
- `<br />`
- `<hr />`

In this or that browser, this or that element may allow for pseudo elements being rendered. I personally wouldn't want to rely on that, though, as it appears that this is non-standards behaviour which may be removed any time in the future.

To solve your problem, hide your checkbox, wrap everything ain a `label` and go with `:checked` pseudo class and adjacent sibling selector `+` to put your "icon" on your `b:before`.

https://jsfiddle.net/1jj1714e/1/

Comment: ok, thanks, so what should i change in my code, to perform same task.

Answer (score 1):

There is already an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4660434/2593588) about why you **cannot** use the :after and :before pseudo-element on an input field.

In brief, it is a "non-standard conformance" that it works "perfectly fine" on chrome.

Comment: ok, thanks, so what should i change in my code, to perform same task.